# Old school Win32 Message Only Window cannot receive messages

Tags: c++, winapi, sendmessage

I'm realize the console win32 app does not quit cleanly so I'm trying to switch to message only windows instead. I'm starting the app from another process and trying to kill it cleanly.

This is the win32 app, it spawns a calc.exe on startup and on clean shutdown, it should kill the calc.exe

```
LRESULT CALLBACK    WindowProc (HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_USER:   PostQuitMessage (0); break;
    default: return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int CALLBACK WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int show)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc = { 0 };
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass1";

    RegisterClassEx (&wc);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx (NULL,
                L"WindowClass1",    // name of the window class
                L"Our First Windowed Program",   // title of the window
                0,
                //WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,    // window style
                300,300,500,400,
                HWND_MESSAGE,
                //NULL,    // parent window, NULL
                NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    //ShowWindow (hWnd, SW_HIDE);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    CreateWindowProcess (L"calc.exe", pi); // helper class to createprocess

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (true)
    {
        if (PeekMessage (&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if (WM_QUIT == msg.message)
                break;
            TranslateMessage (&msg);
            DispatchMessage (&msg);
        }
    }

    // terminate the spawn process, this is not called cleanly
    TerminateProcess (pi.hProcess, 0);
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

I made a c# program to start/kill the app cleanly (the calc.exe gets destroyed) by sending a WM_QUIT/WM_CLOSE/WM_USER message . The Win32 App does not receive messages unless the window is visible (WS_OVERLAPPED and ShowWindow true). PostMessage WM_QUIT is received but the calc.exe does not get destroyed, meaning it is not a clean exit.

How should I kill it cleanly from C# app?

```
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport ("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool    PostMessage (IntPtr hwnd, uint msg, int wparam, int lparam);

        [DllImport ("User32.dll")]
        public static extern int     SendMessage (IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, int wParam, int lParam);

        static void                                                             Main (string [] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Process myProcess;
                myProcess = Process.Start ("My.exe");

                // Display physical memory usage 5 times at intervals of 2 seconds.
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    if (myProcess.HasExited) break;
                    else
                    {
                        // Discard cached information about the process.
                        myProcess.Refresh ();
                        Thread.Sleep (4000);

                        Console.WriteLine ("Sending Message");

                        const int WM_USER = 0x0400;
                        const int WM_CLOSE = 0xF060;      // Command code for close window
                        const int WM_QUIT = 0x0012;

                        // Received only when windows is visible
                        //int result = SendMessage (myProcess.MainWindowHandle, WM_USER, 0, 0);

                        // not clean exit
                        PostMessage (myProcess.MainWindowHandle, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
                        // doesn't receive
                        SendMessage (myProcess.MainWindowHandle, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I'm realize the console win32 app does not quit cleanly` - there surely are ways to do cleanup before a console application exists. Have you looked into [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler) function?

Comment: yes, I have looked at SetControlCtrlHandler, I can trap Ctrl-C and such but it does not cleanup cleanly too.

Comment: OK, worked for me multiple times. If you want to stick with the approach in your question that is OK, otherwise consider asking a question about the console/SetConsoleCtrlHandler approach and describe what exactly did not work out for you.

Comment: That's good to know. Did u spawn it from another process? If I run the console exe, yes I can get it to quit cleanly. It's from another process that I can't.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to actually achieve. If you just want to make sure that a process (say, that you started) exits, when you do - no matter what (e.g. even with a hard kill), use Win32 job objects.

Comment: That is entirely the point of a message-only window, the feature intentionally limits what a window can do.  For one made to not be capable of receiving messages from other processes.  That is an advantage, nobody can mess with the process.  But of course not something you like right now.  Fwiw, WM_QUIT is one of the few messages that is always safe to send with PostThreadMessage().

Comment: My undestanding from the MSDN doc is the message window is able to send and receive messages, but its unclear whether it mean only to local process, or does it work across process

A message-only window enables you to send and receive messages. It is not visible, has no z-order, cannot be enumerated, and does not receive broadcast messages. The window simply dispatches messages.

Comment: You can give a console app the chance to exit cleanly. If it's known to be a console group leader, attach to its console, and send it (the group) Ctrl+Break. Otherwise set a control handler that ignores Ctrl+Break and broadcast it to process group 0. Another option is to close the console window. If attached, you can get the window handle directly via `GetConsoleWindow`. Or get it indirectly by enumerating windows, which works if the target is the effective owner of the console (usually the process that allocated it). Its handler has 5 seconds to exit cleanly in response to a Ctrl+Close event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processes on Windows do not really have a "MainWindow". Process.MainWindowHandle is C# making a guess, and it guesses by looking to see if the process in question has a window with focus - which will only find visible windows. Use `FindWindowEx` to find the window handle you want to close.

Next, when a window closes, it does not automatically try to exit the current threads message loop. You need to handle `WM_DESTROY` to call `PostQuitMessage`.

In your message loop use `GetMessage` rather than `PeekMessage` if you are not doing any other work as `PeekMessage` returns immediately if there are no messages meaning the application thread will never have an opportunity to sleep.

With these changes in place you should be fine to simply post a `WM_CLOSE` to the valid window handle as it will be destroyed, post itself a `WM-QUIT` message to exit the message loop, and terminate the calc process properly.

Comment: I actually do have WM_DESTROY to post QuitMessage, the sample above is stripped out  as it is not called at all.

the PeekMessage is because there are some processing that I stripped out too.

I will try FindWindowEX but I thought since I created the process ,the window handle should be the valid one.

Comment: Ok the FindWindowEx works, I can send WM_QUIT to shutdown cleanly. Thanks!

Comment: WM_QUIT does not shutdown cleanly. Send WM_CLOSE if possible.